# Jquery Drag to Delete

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, jquery-ui

I am currently playing with some jquery and as i tried to create a simple todo-list I came across a problem.

So far the goal is to be able to add paragraphs by clicking the green square and remove them by clicking it once and then dragging it to the red square.

Everything works out fine except the deleting of the dragged paragraph.

Right now it only works by removing the whole class but I want to only delete the dragged one.

Here the code: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OXXXpY

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var send = $("#send");
  var dlt = $("#delete");

  send.click(function() {

      var input = $("input").val();

      $("#container").prepend("<p class='entry'>" + input + "</p>");


  });

  $(document).on("click", ".entry", function() {

      $(this).draggable();
      $("#delete").droppable({

        drop: function() {$(".entry").remove();}
      });
  });


});
```

Please don't mind my English and the real use of this project. This is just an jQuery experiment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$(this)` to target the dragged element

```
$(document).on("click", ".entry", function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      $(this).draggable();
      $("#delete").droppable({

        drop: function() {
          $($this).remove();
        }
      });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var send = $("#send");
  var dlt = $("#delete");

  send.click(function() {

      var input = $("input").val();
      $("#container").prepend("<p class='entry'>" + input + "</p>");

  });

  $(document).on("click", ".entry", function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      $(this).draggable();
      $("#delete").droppable({
        drop: function() { $($this).remove(); }
      });
  });

});
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}
h1 {
  font-family: Helvetica;
}
form input {
  width: 500px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
form input:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.inline {
  display: inline-block;
}
#send {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: green;
}
#delete {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: red;

}
.entry {
  font-family: helvetica;
  border: solid 1px grey;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<h1>ToDo</h1>
<form class="">
        <div class="inline" id="delete"></div>
          <input type="text" name="input" value="">
        <div class="inline" id="send"></div>
</form>
<div id="container"></div>
```